# 404 when trying to deploy Flask app to Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Flask app to my Linux based server with no success. I have already looked through different approaches and entries on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work. To test it a little cleaner, I have created a simple test application that I am trying to run locally:

In `/var/www/test`:

test.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index ():
        return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

test.wsgi

```
from test import app as application
```

and an empty `__init__.py` file.

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName *Local IP address*

    WSGIDaemonProcess test user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test/test.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/test>
        WSGIProcessGroup test
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The test.conf file was registered via `a2ensite test.conf` and `libapache2-mod-wsgi` was installed via apt on my local Debian Buster distribution I am testing this on (localhost). Python2 and 3 are installed together with Flask for each of them. Every file and the `test` folder are owned by www-data with the group www-data. And of course I am restarting the application after every change with `service apache2 restart`.

I can successfully run the application with `python test.py` on localhost:5000, printing "Hello World!".

I don't see anything suspicious in the Apache error-log either, just:

```
[Sun Oct 27 22:16:55.923721 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 26336:tid 140548964586624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 27 22:16:55.923771 2019] [core:notice] [pid 26336:tid 140548964586624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

What am I missing? Why am I getting a 404? Is there any way to see, if the application is even running or just attempting to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServerName *Local IP address*` <- this. You can't use an IP there, it has to be a hostname (that matches the one you use in the URL you access). If you use an IP to access your server, it will default to the first defined vhost, as it won't match any of the Servernames, which is probably not the one you just defined.

So either put a hostname there and define it in your `hosts` file if it's a name that doesn't resolve, or edit the default vhost (vhosts are loaded in alphanumerical order, which mean unless `test.conf` is the first entry when listing `sites-available`, it is not the first one and will not be used when accessing the server with an IP).

Comment: I changed it to localhost, but it still did not work. After changing the VirtualHost from `*` to `*:80`, it worked. I am now getting a 500 on the desired page, but I am assuming that is due to some other issue.

Comment: The value you use after `VirtualHost` in their declarations is tied to which Virtualhosts are defined earlier in the config. It is indeed `*:80` by default. For your 500, yes, check Apache's `error_log` and see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Apparently, I needed to install the Flask package system wide via `apt-get install python-flask`. Using a virtualenv may avoid this. Will see.